# How to identify DATETIME NULL record in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, null

I am developing a tsql query below.  How do I identify the records which contain "1900%" in them?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TICKET, COMPLAINT_LEVEL, COMPLETION_DATE, DATE_FILTER, YEAR(DATE_FILTER) AS YEAR_FILTER, MONTH(DATE_FILTER) AS MONTH_FILTER,
left(datename(month, DATE_FILTER), 3) + ' ''' +
RIGHT(year(DATE_FILTER), 2) AS SHORT_DATE_FILTER,
CASE WHEN DATE_FILTER < MONTH_END AND MONTH_END < CURRENT_DATE_END AND COMPLETION_DATE IS NULL THEN DATE_FILTER 
 WHEN DATE_FILTER < MONTH_END AND MONTH_END < CURRENT_DATE_END AND
 COMPLETION_DATE IS NOT NULL AND ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, COMPLETION_DATE, MONTH_END)) >= 1 AND DATE_FILTER < CURRENT_DATE_END THEN DATE_FILTER
 ELSE 0 END AS ROW_TYPE
FROM #TEMP
--WHERE row_type = 0
--line above does not work
```

And this is what my output looks like
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE DATEPART(year, ROW_TYPE) = 1900
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no datetime that has the null value.

Although it looks tempting to just check the row_type. It will not work, it is a computed column. You need to change your script to this in order to check for the row_type, otherwise you need to compare with the whole expression generating the computed column.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TICKET, COMPLAINT_LEVEL, COMPLETION_DATE, DATE_FILTER, YEAR(DATE_FILTER) AS YEAR_FILTER, MONTH(DATE_FILTER) AS MONTH_FILTER, 
left(datename(month, DATE_FILTER), 3) + ' ''' + 
RIGHT(year(DATE_FILTER), 2) AS SHORT_DATE_FILTER, 
CASE WHEN DATE_FILTER < MONTH_END AND MONTH_END < CURRENT_DATE_END AND COMPLETION_DATE IS NULL THEN DATE_FILTER  
 WHEN DATE_FILTER < MONTH_END AND MONTH_END < CURRENT_DATE_END AND 
 COMPLETION_DATE IS NOT NULL AND ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, COMPLETION_DATE, MONTH_END)) >= 1 AND DATE_FILTER < CURRENT_DATE_END THEN DATE_FILTER 
 ELSE 0 END AS ROW_TYPE 
FROM #TEMP ) a
WHERE YEAR(ROW_TYPE) = 1900
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work as well:

```
WHERE ROW_TYPE = 0
```

But, as [@t-clausen.dk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585141/how-to-identify-datetime-null-record-in-t-sql/6585311#6585311) has correctly pointed out, the `ROW_TYPE` column cannot be referenced in the WHERE clause of the same SELECT. Commonly you'd add an outer SELECT, to which all the aliases of the inner SELECT would be accessible.

Comment: It will not work in the sql above. You can't compare with a computed column. Even then, it only works for the first day of 1900. That seems to be enough according to the test data though.

Comment: Numbers are incompatible with `date` data type. But `ROW_TYPE` is clearly `datetime`. I can't see why you think this wouldn't work with the above query. This simple example seems to show it would: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT GETDATE() UNION ALL SELECT 0) x(d) WHERE d = 0`. The query returns one row with the `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` value.

Comment: Yes, I can see your point, you are absolutely right. I was concentrating on the comparison itself. Of course, that column is not accessible in the WHERE clause directly, and your suggestion is a very common solution to this. Thanks for being so insistent! :)

Comment: I knew you were focusing on the wrong part of my comment. Often we just know we are right, even when we are not :)